# Custom RSpec formatter to display passed test and result of except

Tags: ruby, rspec, integration-testing

Is there a way to create a custom formatter where the passed test details with a list of except is showed?

A bit of a background for this question: we are trying to migrate to RSpec for our hardware integration and system test. The results should be pushed to CouchDB. What I am trying to achieve is a reporter that could generate a similar YAML output like the following snippet:

```
   {
   "_id": "0006b6f0-c1bd-0135-1a98-455c37fe87f1",
   "_rev": "1-9c9786b4b4681ee8493f182d4fc56ef9",
   "sha1_repo": "68bb327b540097c10683830f0d82acbe54a47f03",
   "steps": [
       {
           "result": "pass",
           "description": "Time for Routing expect OK: 126 micro seconds (DLC and Data also OK)"
       },
       {
           "result": "pass",
           "description": "Time for Routing expect OK: 146 micro seconds (DLC and Data also OK)"
       },
       {
           "result": "pass",
           "description": "Time for Routing expect OK: 162 micro seconds (DLC and Data also OK)"
       }
],
 "time_start": "1513119108000",
   "time_end": "1513119108000",
   "result": "pass",
   "testcase_title": "Komfort_TSG_HBFS_03_to_Komfort2_TSG_HBFS_03",
   "testcase_id": "TC_1zu1_BAF_Komfort_TSG_HBFS_03_to_Komfort2_TSG_HBFS_03",
   "hierarchy": [
       "Hardware Integration Test",
       "1 - Routing",
       "1.1 Normal Routing",
       "1zu1_BAF_TestCases",
       "CAN_to_CAN"
   ]
}
```

With failed test there is no problem to achieve this, but we need also the results from passed test in order to be able to create long term statistics.

I can override the passed event of RSPec but the example object delivers only the description and no more info.

```
class EliteReporter
  RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self, :example_started, :example_passed, :example_failed, :example_finished
  def example_passed(passed)
    @output.printf "pass \n #{passed.example.description}"
  end
end
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally with the help of my colleague and thanks of the [Tip from RSPec Emailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rspec/0tV-k0NAYh0) I could do this.

I have created a Recorder class that collects the test results, than override the Expect methode. This way in the custom formatter I can collect all the passed results:

```
 class ExpectWrapper
  def initialize(_expect, _recorder, _description)
    @expect = _expect
    @recorder = _recorder
    @description = _description
  end

  def to(matcher, failure_message=nil)
    begin
      expect_ret = @expect.to(matcher, failure_message) # test

      # for tests that aggregate failures
      if expect_ret.instance_of?(TrueClass)
        @recorder.record(matcher.actual, matcher.description, @description)
      else
        @recorder.record_error(matcher.actual, matcher.description, failure_message, @description)
      end
      expect_ret
    rescue RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError => e
      # for test that do not aggregate failures
      @recorder.record_error(matcher.actual, matcher.description, failure_message, @description)
      raise e
    end

  end
end

class Recorder
  def self.start
    @@data = []
    return Recorder.new
  end

  def record(expect, data, description)
    @@data << { :pass => true,  :expect => expect, :value => data, :description => description }
    self
  end

  def record_error(expect, data, failure_message, description)
    @@data << { :pass => false, :expect => expect, :value => data, :message => failure_message,  :description => description }
    self
  end

  def self.data
    @@data
  end

  def expect(object, value, description = "")
    return ExpectWrapper.new(object.expect(value), self, description)
  end
end
```

The custom formatter would look the following, is just an example, the data could be than put to JSON and pushed to Couch:

```
class EliteVerboseFormatter
  RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self, :example_started, :example_passed, :example_failed, :example_finished


  def initialize(output)
    @output = output
  end

  def example_passed(notification)
    @output.puts( format_output(notification.example, Recorder) )
  end

  def get_test_name( group, description)
    "#{group.example.example_group}/#{description}".gsub('RSpec::ExampleGroups::','')
  end

  def format_output( example, recorder )
    test_case = get_test_name( example.example_group, example.description)
    str = "**********TEST: #{test_case} ************\n"
    recorder.data.each do |d|
       str += sprintf("%s: ---> expected '%-10s' to '%-20s' DESC: %s \n",  d[:pass] ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL',  d[:expect], d[:value], d[:description])
    end
    str

  end

  def example_failed(notification)
    @output.puts(format_output( notification.example, Recorder))

    exception = notification.exception
    message_lines = notification.fully_formatted_lines(nil, RSpec::Core::Notifications::NullColorizer)
    exception_details = if exception
                          {
                              # drop 2 removes the description (regardless of newlines) and leading blank line
                              :message => message_lines.drop(2).join("\n"),
                              :backtrace => notification.formatted_backtrace.join("\n"),
                          }
                        end

     @output.puts RSpec::Core::Formatters::ConsoleCodes.wrap(exception_details[:message], :failure)

  end


end
```

Comment: Do you have an example repo of these pieces of wode working together ? I cannot reproduce the expected behaviour by simply copy/pasting the given classes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read the [Module: RSpec::Core::Formatters](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Formatters)

you might find something helpful.

P.S. I have used Cucumber for many times, and I once wanted to custom cucumber formatter to display every step's details no matter it failed or passed. I finally got the solution by reading cucumber core documents.so I think maybe rspec core document can help you to find the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but actually I did that. As you see in my example above I have already created a custom formatter. My problem is that I can get only the info that the test has passed but not the reason why it has passed. For example if I check the hardware version over the console I want to see in my report that the version matches to a certain value. This way I know the test is correct, and later I can collect in the database infos how the test has evolved.

Comment: I suppose I know what you real want.  When a test is  passed , you want to get its details in the same formatter of a failed test, is it?Actually I am not familiar with Rspec, but  I have a suggestion that maybe helpful in some way. edit your code  as below :                                                                                       
<br/>
 class EliteReporter
  RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self, :example_started, :example_passed, :example_failed, :example_finished
  def example_passed(example)
      example_failed(example)
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

I find that I cannot put the code in comment, so I put it here.
edit your code as below:

```
class EliteReporter
  RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self, :example_started, :example_passed, :example_failed, :example_finished
  def example_passed(example)
      example_failed(example)
  end
end
```

I hope it can be helpful: )

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem is that when example_passed is triggered there is no exception object created for the example, thus the formatter can't read the infos from it even if I call example_failed.

Comment: How about using before hooks to raise exceptions so that every example will fail even those passed examples? then exception object might be created for the example_passed. uh,  It is just an advice, cause I am afraid I have no other idea on your issue. hope it can be helpful.